# How do I set up the "Show Deskop" shotcut key for the R.A.T 9 mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I've programmed the back button on my [mouse](http://www.cyborggaming.com/prod/rat9.htm) to execute the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Show desktop).
But when I press it, its just opening the Start menu and typing D into any program that was active (ie. Notepad++)

Here's is a screenshot of the configuration program:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

**NOTE:** The Network Folders (forward button) just executes a shortcut for a desktop shortcut which is just a folder with a bunch of shared folder shortcuts. It's shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the key to start a file. Save the following in a file called "showDesktop.scf"

```
[Shell]
Command=2
IconFile=explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop
```